# Strange sentence with nicht nur ... sondern auch

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

**Der Müll nimmt nämlich nicht nur Platz in deiner Wohnung, sondern auch auf deiner Seele weg.**

Shouldn't it be like "Der Müll nimmt den Platz nicht nur in deiner Wohnung". And the second part without "weg". "Garbage takes space not only in your flat, but also in your soul".

Or is there some kind of poetic license involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Platz* is used as an uncountable word here, like *space*. The fixed expression  *Platz wegnehmen* (a *Funktionsverbgefüge*, as @amadeusamadeus pointed out) means *to use up space*. So there's no article needed, and the word *weg* is part of the separated verb.

The order of parts in the sentence is a bit unusual, especially the position of the word *Platz* is bordering to bad style.

The standard order would be either:

> Der Müll nimmt nämlich nicht nur in deiner Wohnung, sondern auch auf deiner Seele Platz weg.

or

> Der Müll nimmt nämlich Platz nicht nur in deiner Wohnung, sondern auch auf deiner Seele weg.

The point is that the whole prepositional adverb "nicht nur in deiner Wohnung, sondern auch auf deiner Seele" refers to *Platz*, but the word order in the original sentence doesn't reflect that. In the *sondern* part, the reference to *Platz* is just implied. It's certainly a correct sentence, and native speakers will definitely use this kind of ellipsis.

Comment: I couldn't stop thinking about "weg" as if it were an adverb, and I was wrong about the article before "Platz", but yeah, the part, that bothered me was the position of "nicht nur". I'm a beginner here, so I tried to shorten the question as much as possible. But anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason why *Platz wegnehmen* has no article is not that it is uncountable (it can have an article: *den (ganzen) Platz wegnehmen*). The reason is the same as for the countable nouns in *Auto fahren* and *Pfeife rauchen*: they are [*Funktionsverbgefüge*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funktionsverbgef%C3%BCge) (cf. Duden-Grammatik, §§ 395, 580).

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: I'm not sure -- you can use Platz as an uncountable noun, right? (Ist noch Platz im Auto, wir müssen noch Platz schaffen/lassen/freihalten/freiräumen, das verbraucht Platz, wieviel Platz habt ihr?) You can define all of these as FVGs if you want, but does that make sense? Why do it with Platz but not with Milch then?

Comment: @HalvarF I'd say that *Milch wegnehmen* (e.g. *meine Mitbewohnerin nimmt Milch weg* ~ *take away milk*) wouldn't work just as well despite being uncountable. *Platz wegnehmen*, however, is a fixed expression with a non-literal meaning (I guess that's also why you translated it as *use up* instead of *take away*) and thus should be a FVG. Indeed I think that most of the other examples would also be FVGs for the same reasons, just like the variations *Bescheid geben/bekommen/erhalten* would all be. Only *Platz verbrauchen/haben* seem indistinguishable from *Milch verbrauchen/haben*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: I see. You're right, "Platz wegnehmen" is an FVG, because "wegnehmen" gets a whole new meaning when used in "Platz wegnehmen". But "Platz" doesn't really change its meaning, it's used as an uncountable word meaning space. Whether you say that there is no article because it's an uncountable noun or because it's an FVG seems a moot point then.

Comment: @HalvarF I absolutely agree that explanations can co-exist, also I may have had a reasoning bias as I just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Word order

No poetic license, but the [*Satzklammer*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satzklammer) is involved.

First of all, the verb is ***wegnehmen*** ('to take **away**'), not simply <s>*nehmen*</s> ('to take'). *Wegnehmen* is a [separable verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb). In a subordinate clause, it is an unit and comes last:

> …, weil (der) Müll Platz **wegnimmt**.

In a main clause with [V2 word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order#V2_in_German),  however, its prefix is separated from the root. The main part comes at the second position (second part of speech), while the prefix comes last:

> Der Müll **nimmt** (den) Platz **weg**.

This is why it is called *Satzklammer* (verbal bracket): The root becomes the left bracket and the prefix becomes the right bracket of the *central field* of the sentence. Only one part of speech must be outside of the sentence bracket, in the so-called first field (*Vorfeld*).

Another case where the prefix is 'separated' from the root (this time by an infix) would be the *zu*-infinitive:

> …, um (den) Platz **weg**zu**nehmen**.

In your sentence, we have a quite long central field, but that's not a problem:

> Der Müll **nimmt** nämlich nicht nur Platz in deiner Wohnung, sondern auch auf deiner Seele **weg**.

- *Der Müll* is the first field,
- *nimmt* is the left bracket,
- *nämlich nicht nur Platz in deiner Wohnung, sondern auch auf deiner Seele* is the central field, and
- *weg* is the right bracket.

---

#### Article of *Platz*

In the example, *Platz* has no article because *Platz wegnehmen* is a *Funktionsverbgefüge* ('functional verbal phrase'), that means that the verb and a 'deverbal' noun that describes the circumstances act like an unit (like *Auto fahren*, *Essen kochen*).